# C# Proxy Server doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-3.5, proxy

I'm working on a proxy server in .NET using sockets, and I've discovered very interested moment in code execution:

1. When I debug code step by step - proxy server works fine
2. When I start proxy server without debugging - I get error in browser.

I really have no idea why it works like I discribed above. Maybe, someone has fixed this problem already?

Here is code of my proxy server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Statistiks.Lib
{
    internal class NetworkMonitor
    {
        private readonly IList<string> _denied;
        private readonly Socket _srvSocket;
        private readonly Thread _srvThread;

        public NetworkMonitor(int port, IList<string> deniedList)
        {
            _denied = deniedList;
            _srvSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                                    ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _srvSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, port));
            _srvThread = new Thread(ProxyServerThread);
            _srvThread.Start(_srvSocket);
        }

        private void ProxyServerThread(object obj)
        {
            var srv = obj as Socket;
            srv.Listen(1024);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = srv.Accept();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(cSocket =>
                    {
                        var client = cSocket as Socket;
                        if (client.Available <= 0)
                        {
                            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            client.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                        var recieveBuf = new byte[client.Available];
                        client.Receive(recieveBuf, SocketFlags.None);
                        var ni = new NetworkInfo();
                        try
                        {
                            ni.Url = new Uri(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuf)
                                                     .Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]
                                                 .Split(' ')[1]);
                        }
                        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                        {
                            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                            client.Close();
                            return;
                        }
                        var forwardedSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
                                                         ProtocolType.Tcp);
                        forwardedSocket.Connect(Dns.GetHostAddresses(ni.Url.Host)[0], ni.Url.Port);
                        forwardedSocket.Send(recieveBuf, SocketFlags.None);
                        recieveBuf = new byte[forwardedSocket.Available];
                        forwardedSocket.Receive(recieveBuf, SocketFlags.None);
                        client.Send(recieveBuf, SocketFlags.None);
                        forwardedSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        forwardedSocket.Disconnect(false);
                        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        client.Disconnect(false);
                        forwardedSocket.Close();
                        client.Close();
                    }, clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }

    internal struct NetworkInfo
    {
        internal Uri Url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue. Most likely you check for data available before any has been received, causing the connection to be closed. Also, use a while loop to receive data (some of it may be ready to read, but perhaps not yet everything).

Answer (score 0):

The different results under the debugger are probably because all your data fits in the socket buffer, and the extra delay from debugging allows all the data to arrive before the call to `Receive`.

Under normal execution, however, this is not the case. The data will arrive in packets, and in order to know where the end of data is, you have to parse your HTTP request. Socket's `Available` property only indicates how much data is in the buffer *at the moment*, it is not the length of the entire message. While it is definitely possible to read using raw sockets, it is easier to use a `NetworkStream`:

```
IEnumerable<string> ReadRequestHeaders(Socket s)
{
    using (var stream = new NetworkStream(s, false))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == "")
                break;

            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```

The same goes for the rest of the HTTP message - in order to correctly forward it, you will have to know where it ends, which means understanding Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding fields and parsing accordingly.